# Parse JSON File for Option in HTML select box

Tags: html, json, parsing, cordova

I'm doing PhoneGap project for my company.. Here goes on..
I have json file named city.json

```
[{"CityID":1,"CityName":"Magelang"},{"CityID":2,"CityName":"Jayapura"},{"CityID":3,"CityName":"Aceh"}]
```

I only want to get this city data for the option in my html select box named "city".. I had searched on the web, but couldn't find any solution for this JSON pattern.. I have tried this code, but it didn't work..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.getJSON('city.json', 
            function(data){
                var html = '';
                var len = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
                    html += '<option value="' + data[i].CityID + '">' + data[i].CityName + '</option>';
                }
                $('#city').appendTo(html);
            });
        });
```

I have imported the jquery javascript plugin too.. I really have no idea to make it works..
Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append()` not `.appendTo()`. The way you are doing it you are trying to append `$("city")` to your `html` variable.

Comment: sorry for the mistakes.. had fixed it.. but still didn't work..
is there any other file I should import other than jquery.js to make the code works?

Comment: All the functions you are using are stock jQuery so there is nothing else to include. Have you tested to make sure you are getting the content of the file in your data variable with `console.log(data)` or `alert(data.toString())`?

Comment: never. Where should I put it? in the bracket inside function(data){}? sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: anyway, I include this function in <script> bracket in the top of my html file. Did I place it wrong?

Comment: Yes. First thing after `function(data){` you should put `alert(data.toString())`. This will show exactly what is in your data variable when the `.getJSON` request responds.

Comment: As long as it is included after the line where you include jquery.js it should be fine.

Comment: hmm I've tested alert(data.toString()) in my code, but seems like it doesn't work too.. There's no any reaction..

Comment: Or maybe is this jQuery code won't work in Android? can I map this JSON file content into array of variable maybe?

Comment: If `alert()` isn't working I would think there is something wrong somewhere else in your code - alert is a standard browser feature/function and still should show an empty alert box if there was nothing set in the `data` variable. The content of your JSON file IS already a Javascript array - there is no need to map it to an array.

Comment: okay thanks.. Now the alert() is working and read my data :D
I have mistakenly import the jquery.js..
but now the problem is how could I populate the json data into the options in select box? My code couldn't work..

Comment: finally I get my code works :D
The mistake is I haven't added the attribute class='city' in my <select>.. Thanks for the answers.. :D